# Consuming with Kafkacat shows no messages, although using -o beginning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kcat

I'm trying to consume from a topic using Kafkacat , using the following command:

```
kafkacat -b *****:9093 -C -K\t -X security.protocol=SASL_SSL -X sasl.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512 -X sasl.username=**** -X sasl.password=**** -t **** -o beginning
```

The response for the command is:

```
% Reached end of topic **** [0] at offset 121507
% Reached end of topic **** [2] at offset 186701
% Reached end of topic **** [1] at offset 175697
```

Now - Shouldn't the flag -o beginning show me all of the messages? I'm trying to understand how to begin at the first offset without success

Comment: How are we supposed to know if the topic isn't empty?

Comment: It is not, since it has positive large offsets in all partitions.. I just want to read them all from the beginning

Comment: Offsets never decrease. The beginning and the end could be the same, positive large offset